# Calling SetField on a DataRow with the same value causes changes?

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

Somewhat confused here, the following code causes changes in the DataTable when I would not expect it to do so. Is there no actual individual value change management inside of a DataTable? Or am I missing something?

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add("Sample Name");
table.AcceptChanges();

table.Rows[0].SetField("Name", "Sample Name");

var changes = table.GetChanges();

// expecting null, actually returns changes
```

I would have expected internally the table to use some pre-built logic to determine whether or not the new value is indeed different from the current value.

Why is it done like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you modify content of a row, it updates the [`DataRow.RowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx) property, which can hold `UnChanged`, `Added`, `Modified` etc. Later `DataTable.GetChanges` filter out rows based on that row status. **It is irrespective of the value**.

[DataTable.GetChanges - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxfaha8.aspx)

> Gets a copy of the DataTable containing all changes made to it since
>   it was last loaded, or since AcceptChanges was called, **filtered by
>   DataRowState.**

Also see:

[Row States and Row Versions - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww3k31w0.aspx)

> ADO.NET manages rows in tables using row states and versions. A row
>   state indicates the status of a row; row versions maintain the values
>   stored in a row as it is modified, including current, original, and
>   default values. For example, **after you have made a modification to a
>   column in a row, the row will have a row state of Modified**, and two
>   row versions: Current, which contains the current row values, and
>   Original, which contains the row values before the column was
>   modified.

Comment: You missed my question. I am saying that given my code (and it is indeed correct) it shouldn't have given me any changes because I haven't actually changed any values. Yes, I called SetField - but it was the value that is already in the table.

Comment: @reedparkes, just updated my answer. Couldn't understand it earlier.

Comment: So, basically, you have to manually test whether or not you are setting to the same value. That is... annoying.

Comment: Well be fair. The tables are designed to hold all types of values (base type being object) so if it tries to do the comparison itself it may not necessarily be able to (custom type) or be able to do so accurately (wont know if "1" is an int or string).

Comment: While true, I would argue using IEqualityComparer<T>.

Comment: @Habib Maybe I'm misunderstanding you but it does not get overridden. How else would RejectChanges work? You can access the old value via row.Field<string>("Name", DataRowVersion.Original)

Comment: @reedparkes, ah, ignore my comment plz. You are right. I need coffee

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a design feature as even calling the `SetField()` extension method with exactly the same object and then checking the field values in `DataRowVersion.Original` and `DataRowVersion.Current` you can find that they are still reference equal. There is no documentation describing a different behavior.